# Why does a data.table sometimes require hitting "enter" twice to print?

Tags: r, data.table

Sometimes a data.table requires hitting the "enter" button twice to print on Rstudio.

Why does this happen?

Comment: see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#why-do-i-have-to-type-dt-sometimes-twice-after-using-to-print-the-result-to-console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is rather an old issue. The way to solve it is to put an empty `[]` immediately after your final call of the `data.table`. Something like the following.

```
foo = function(x) {
    # do stuff here which return a data.table called DT
    return(DT[])
}

test = foo(x)
test # this will be printed right away.
```