Why does chaining and assignment require you to enter the variable twice in console before it appears?
I have an example below that results in nothing appearing in the last line when it is run in my RStudio console. However, running it again the second time shows what final_counts is. Why does this happen?
library(data.table)
# Example data.table
activity_logs <- data.table(
  user_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5),
  activity_time = as.POSIXct(c(
    "2024-01-01 10:00:00", "2024-01-02 11:00:00", "2024-01-03 12:00:00",
    "2024-01-01 09:00:00", "2024-01-04 14:00:00",
    "2024-01-01 08:00:00", "2024-01-03 10:00:00", "2024-01-05 16:00:00",
    "2024-01-02 07:00:00", "2024-01-03 11:00:00",
    "2024-01-02 12:00:00", "2024-01-03 13:00:00"
  )),
  activity_type = c(
    "login", "purchase", "purchase", "login", "purchase",
    "login", "purchase", "purchase", "login", "purchase", "login", "login"
  )
)

purchase_counts <- activity_logs[activity_type == "purchase", .(total_purchases = .N), by = user_id]
max_purchases <- max(purchase_counts$total_purchases, na.rm = TRUE)
all_purchase_counts <- data.table(purchases = 1:max_purchases)
user_purchase_counts <- purchase_counts[, .N, by = total_purchases]
final_counts <- user_purchase_counts[all_purchase_counts, on = .(total_purchases = purchases), all = TRUE, nomatch = NA][is.na(N), N := 0]
final_counts


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60965311/why-does-a-data-table-sometimes-require-hitting-enter-twice-to-print Also https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#why-do-i-have-to-type-dt-sometimes-twice-after-using-to-print-the-result-to-console from the same post
